# Quotient Group Proof Help

Tags: abstract-algebra, proof-verification

Let G and H be finite groups with (|G|,|H|) = 1. If ϕ:G-->H is a homomorphism, show ϕ is the trivial homomorphism.

proof:
Let G and H be finite groups with (|G|,|H|) = 1. Suppose ϕ:G-->H is a homomorphism, so ϕ(G) is a subgroup of H.
Then by first isomorphism theorem, G/kerϕ is isomorphic to ϕ(G).
So |G/kerϕ| = |ϕ(G)|
Then |G|/|kerϕ| = |ϕ(G)|
Since ϕ(G) is a subgroup of H, |ϕ(G)|/|H|
Then |ϕ(G)|x = |H| for some x
So |ϕ(G)| = |H|/x
Thus, |G|/||kerϕ| = |H|/x
So x|G| = |H||kerϕ|
Now suppose ϕ is nontrivial. Then |G| < |kerϕ|
So |G|/|kerϕ| > 1 and |H|/|ϕ(G)| > 2
Thus (|G|,|H|) > 1/ Hence a contradiction.
Therefore, ϕ is trivial.

Is this correct?

Comment: What does $(|G|,|H|)$ mean? Is it the gcd (greatest common denominator) of their orders or something?

Comment: That is all it says on the paper. I am thinking that it is the gcd of their orders. That is what I took it as.

Answer (score 1):

I think you got a little off track after the first few lines. You have that $$|\phi(G)|=\frac{|G|}{|\ker{\phi}|}$$ This means that $$|\ker{\phi}|=\frac{|G|}{|\phi(G)|}$$ so the order of $\phi(G)$ divides the order of $G$. But as you said, $\phi(G)$ is a subgroup of $H$, and since all subgroups divide the orders of their groups, the order of $\phi(G)$ also divides $|H|$. Since it divides both, we must have that $$(|G|,|H|)\ge |\phi(G)|$$ But $$(|G|,|H|)=1$$ so $$|\phi(G)|=1$$ If it has only one element and it is a group, it must contain the identity - therefore $\phi$ is the trivial homomorphism $\phi(g)=e_{H}$.